# Outbound url query token is breaking AJAX callbacks

Tags: 7, ajax, uri

I am running into a strange situation that I don't really understand. I am appending a query token to all outbound url query strings using [hook_url_outbound_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  $options['query']['token'] = 'sometoken';
}
```

It is my understanding that $options is passed by reference and can be modified in place. According to the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) documentation, the query option should be a key/value-pair. So I believe I am doing this right.

The strange thing I am noticing is that I am seeing this in my logs.

> REFERRING PAGE:
>   http://example.com/node/1?token=sometoken
>
> LOCATION: http://example.com/?q=masquerade/autocomplete&token=sometoken/b

I somehow get the idea the `b` (my input in the ajax field) should have been appended to the `q` and not to the `token` query parameter.

So I have thought of two possible solutions, but have so far failed to implement any of them:

1. Remove the url token on AJAX links (but there is no way to tell if a link is an AJAX link).
2. Change the order of the query parameters in hook_url_outbound_alter by removing and re-adding the `q` query token.

   ```
   if (isset($options['query']['q'])) {
     $q = $options['query']['q'];
     unset($options['query']['q']);
     $options['query']['q'] = $q;
   }
   ```

Does anyone have another idea on how to fix this?

**Update**

In fact I think this cannot be fixed with method 2 due to the following code from the url() function.

```
// Without Clean URLs.
  else {
    $path = $prefix . $path;
    $query = array();
    if (!empty($path)) {
      $query['q'] = $path;
    }
    if ($options['query']) {
      // We do not use array_merge() here to prevent overriding $path via query
      // parameters.
      $query += $options['query'];
    }
    $query = $query ? ('?' . drupal_http_build_query($query)) : '';
    $script = isset($options['script']) ? $options['script'] : '';
    return $base . $script . $query . $options['fragment'];
  }
```

So any other ideas?